# What's the point in ASP.NET AJAX?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

So, I'm new to ASP.NET and also relatively new to jQuery although I've had a fair amount of experience using this now, and think it's great.

The only downside of course is that for users without Javascript it doesn't work.

When I first got reading about ASP.NET AJAX I mis-interpreted the way it worked and thought that it did a lot of Javascript processing on the server, thus, I assumed making it compatible with Javascript-disabled browsers.

Having experimented now with both, I see this is wrong.

Basically, the UpdatePanel for submitting forms is dead easy to use, which is nice, but a lot of the other plugins that I have been experimenting with from http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ just seem to be slower versions of those that the jQuery UI can offer.

I particularly want to use the HTMLEditor that comes with ASP.NET AJAX, but when I ran a sample on my test site, it was desperately slow to load.

Also, having included jQuery in my MasterPage my UpdatePanels don't work anymore, so it seems picking the best bits from each is not going to work as intended.

Comment: If the question you actually want answered is "What's the point in ASP.NET AJAX" then this is a bit like a Java developer saying "What's the point in C#?" - there is usually more than one approach to a problem!  If you are having specific problems with the product then that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the post below that they can play nicely together:

http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/10/07/make-them-to-love-each-other-asp-net-ajax-updatepanels-amp-javascript-jquery-functions.aspx

As you say they both do fairly similar things and I don't see any point in loading both the frameworks when one would do.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays jquery and other modern toolkits make doing Ajax apps pretty disturbingly easy. Back in 2006 when the first versions of asp.net Ajax, née asp.net atlas, appeared it wasn't so easy, eapecially with how asp.net web forms operated. So there was a point initially -- to provide asp.net developers a gateway drug into the world of Ajax.

Nowadays one is typically better off using a more modern Ajax framework and tools.